# What is 5 equal to?

Tags: logical-deduction

Can you find what corresponds to 5?

If:
$$1=5$$
$$2=6$$
$$3=7$$
$$4=8$$

then,
$$5=?$$

**Note:** the answer is not 9.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Is the answer simply

> 1, due to symmetry (thanks for the correction, @Peter!!) of the equals sign?

Comment: Why are my puzzles so easy for you?!

Comment: @WaisKamal Because **El** is short for **Elite** :D

Comment: @WaisKamal I have already seen this puzzle in some mobile game I think

Comment: @user477343 good point!

Comment: I think you mean symmetry, instead of commutativity.

Comment: Thanks @Peter, that I do. Will credit you and update the answer!

Comment: @WaisKamal, well, I also came up with this solution in seconds.

Answer (score 8):

It is:

> ? (question mark), that's by definition.

Comment: Good thinking! (though not the right answer)

Comment: I don't mind downvoting but what is wrong with my answer to make you do that?

Answer (score 7):

> **22**, using the [OEIS sequence A098670](https://oeis.org/A098670)

or literally,

> **not 9.**

Comment: I don't understand that sequence. The $a(n)$'th digit of WHAT is a 2? Is there something missing in the description?

Comment: @Vincent - the $a(n)$'th digit of the sequence itself. The sequence starts with 5, must be growing as slow as possible, and (since it starts with 5) its 5th digit must be 2. Hence 5, 6, 7, 8, 22... work from there.

Answer (score 6):

> Well, since the first equation says:
>  `1 = 5`
>  I would say the solution is:
>  `5 = 1`

Comment: Damn, @El-Guest got there first, buddy. That rule is lame, in my opinion. This is about puzzling, not some kind of competition :\

Comment: Oh, shame on me :(

Comment: Correct answer but as stated by @user477343, El-Guest answered first. I will upvote all answers, but accept the one that came first.

Answer (score 5):

its-

> 1, assuming  $=$ signs work as they normally do, if $1=5$ then $5=1$ would be true

Comment: El-Guest got it first

Answer (score 3):

It is

> 13. Replacing 5 with 1+4 or 2+3 and substituting those numbers from the given list, we find 5+8 or 6+7. Both equal 13.

Answer (score 1):

For mathematicians, it could be :

> $5=1$

Because,

> $n_1 = n_2 [5] + 1$

As a result :

> $1 = 5[5] + 1 = 0 + 1$

As well as

> $2 = 6[5] + 1 = 1 + 1$

And

> $4 = 4[5] + 1 = 3 + 1$

Finally :

> $5 = 5[5] + 1 = 1$

Using :

> [Modulo Operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

Answer (score 1):

> As,
> 1 = 5  
> So,
> 5 = 1  
> Note: the answer is not 9.

Answer (score 1):

1 = 5
Therefore, 5 = 1
That would not be true if polynomial of certain degree was given.

Comment: Welcome to puzzling.SE! Not bad, but this is basically what the accepted answer is saying.